# Play Store rejecting app bundle for required automotive feature, but the feature is not marked as required in manifest

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm attempting to upload a new version of our app that supports android Auto to the beta track on the Play Console, but the Play Store is rejecting the bundle with error:

```
Forbidden

Problem:

APKs and Android App Bundles must not require following features: android.hardware.type.automotive.
```

However, it is an optional feature for the app and states as such in the manifest:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.automotive" android:required="false" />`

I have looked through the latest samples and documentation for any changes that may be causing this, but I have found nothing. I have also checked using the merged manifest comparison tool that the value is not being overwritten during build.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Check in manifest of all the modules or newly added libraries

Comment: I neglected to mention that I have verified using the manifest merge tool in android studio  that the value remains false. I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: this post might help you for getting to know more about uses-feature https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112865/will-an-optional-device-type-specific-permission-hide-my-game-in-the-play-store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question for anyone who might run into this.

May seem obvious, but my fix for the error was to simply remove the uses-feature element for automotive from my manifest.

I never found exact clarification, but I can only assume Play Store is now rejecting the android.hardware.type.automotive feature as its been repurposed for Automotive OS.

Documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/auto no longer mentions adding the feature to manifest for supporting Android Auto, but it does mention it is required for Automotive OS (in addition to a separate module / build), but my app only support Android Auto at this time.

This was confusing because documentation for the automotive feature elsewhere (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element) does not mention this change.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me recently while trying to publish an Android Automotive OS app, which really requires

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.automotive" android:required="true" />
```

The reason for this is because you need to make sure you select the right release type in the Google Play Console:

[image]

In this case, *Automotive OS* only needs to be selected before creating the release track.

Comment: What about test track? The select option does'nt show there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The Automotive OS form factor also supports internal track.